# SOS extension for x64 debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2012, sos

Is there any posibility to load SOS extension in visual studio 2010/2012 (.Net framework 4) for x64 process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install VS2012 *and* the [WDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx), you can attach to a 64 bit process via the User Mode Debugger transport protocol (option under the attach to process dialog). If you do that, you can load SOS from the new Debugger Immediate Window. This works for both 32 and 64 bit processes.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. For debugging 64 bit applications with SOS, you have to use windbg.